# Ao Digitar no Input carregar outra pagina sem precisar de botao submit

Tags: html, input, automatização

Tenho uma página onde possui um input que carrega dados de código de barras quando abre um aplicativo no celular.

Ao scanear o código de barras do produto e carregar o código no input, gostaria de fazer com que a página redirecionasse para pagina de busca daquele código escaneado sem precisar clicar no botão enviar(submit).

Hoje minha página já funciona com o botão de enviar, mas tenho que escanear o produto pela câmera do celular e depois apertar o botão de enviar, queria automatizar essa tarefa ao carregar o código já fizesse esse enviar automaticamente. Segue o código:

```
<form action="consultar-item.php" method="POST">
       <div class="form-group form-control-lg col-md-4">
        <label for="cod">Busque o Codigo de Barras:</label>

        (<a href="http://zxing.appspot.com/scan?ret=http://localhost:8084/appteste/index.php?codigo={CODE}">Leitor</a>):

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cod" value="<?= $_GET['codigo'] ?>"   />
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="form-group form-control-lg col-md-3">
        <label for="date1">Data Inicial da Pesquisa:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date1" />
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="form-group form-control-lg col-md-3">
        <label for="date2">Data Final da Pesquisa:</label>
        <input type="date"  class="form-control" name="date2" />
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-group form-control-lg col-md-2">
        <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-success" name="busca" id="butContato" value="ENVIAR" 
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Não teria como fazer um if/else com um setTimeout dentro e com uma função que faz o submit se o valor recebido no input for válido? Talvez nem precise do setTimeout... ou vc pode fazer um setInterval pra ficar verificando, e se for true vc faz o submit. Aqui tem algo que pode te ajudar https://www.formget.com/javascript-auto-submit-form/

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada e depois respondo, Obrigado!

Comment: No evento `onchange` do input não dá para fazer o submit via js?

Answer (score 2):

Não tenho total domínio de JS, mas como comentei vc pode ter um `setInterval` que fica verificando o `input` que recebe o  código, e se o valor desse `input` for diferente de 0, (na regra que fiz) ele envia o `form`, mas vc pode fazer ali o que quiser para validar o campo e assim enviar ou não.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seque o código da imagem acima.

```js
let inp = document.querySelector('input');
let form = document.querySelector('form');

let con = '';

function enviar() {
  if(inp.value != con){
    document.body.style.background = "red";
    console.log('leu o código de barra');
    
    // form.submit(); Descomente isso caso queira que o form seja enviado
  } 
}

setInterval(enviar, 200);
```

```html
<form method="post" action="envia.php">
  <input type="text" id="" name="">      
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```